# Java Android Basic game - Saving a HighScore using shared preferences - TOTAL BEGINNER

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am a total beginner to Java Android programming. I'm creating a basic android game using Eclipse and I want to save a High Score. I've been told to use shared preferences so when I exit the game and open it again, the high score is saved. I've already got the High score to save on my 'main Menu' page but very confused about where to put the shared preferences code? Should it be in my OnCreate? Please look at my code and try and help me out. I know its probably pretty simple but I've been working on this for a while.

CODE BELOW:

```
package cct.mad.lab;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.SharedPreferences.Editor;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import cct.mad.lab.GameView;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.media.SoundPool;
import android.net.Uri;

public class MainMenu extends Activity {

    //MediaPlayer backgroundmusic;////////////////////

    private static final int SCORE_REQUEST_CODE = 1;// The request code for the intent

    private static final int PREFERENCE_MODE_PRIVATE = 0;

    TextView tvHighScore;
    TextView tvLastScore;
    //TextView tvScore
    String score;
    Intent gameIntent;
    int HighNum = 0;
    SoundPool sp;
    MediaPlayer mp;
    int hit = 0;
    ImageView crash;
    ImageView image;
    //int highscore = 0;



    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.game_start);
        tvHighScore = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvGuessGame);
        tvLastScore = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.LastGameNumb);


    }

    public void startGame(View v)

    {
        gameIntent = new Intent(this,GameActivity.class);
        startActivityForResult(gameIntent, SCORE_REQUEST_CODE );  

        mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.bgmusic); // Assigns the media player to the bgmusic in the raw flder
        mp.setLooping(true); // loops the media player so it continues to play
        mp.start(); // starts the media player when the start game button is called
    } 


    /* Create Options Menu */
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 
    {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }


    // Respond to item selected on OPTIONS MENU
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle item selection
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        //put data in Intent
        case R.id.easy:
            Toast.makeText(this, "Easy chosen", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        case R.id.medium:
            Toast.makeText(this, "Medium chosen", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        case R.id.hard:
            Toast.makeText(this, "Hard chosen", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        case R.id.other:
            Toast.makeText(this, "Other chosen", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }


    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent retIntent) {

    mp.pause(); // Pauses the Mediaplayer when the game is stopped and returned to the main menu.

        // Check which request we're responding to
        if (requestCode == SCORE_REQUEST_CODE) {
            // Make sure the request was successful
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                if (retIntent.hasExtra("GAME_SCORE")) 
                {
                    int scoreFromGame = retIntent.getExtras().getInt("GAME_SCORE");

                    if (scoreFromGame > HighNum) 
                    {
                    tvHighScore.setText(Integer.toString(scoreFromGame));   
                    tvLastScore.setText(Integer.toString(scoreFromGame));   
                    HighNum = scoreFromGame;
                    }   

                    else if (scoreFromGame > HighNum) 
                    {
                        tvHighScore.setText(Integer.toString(scoreFromGame));   
                        tvLastScore.setText(Integer.toString(scoreFromGame));   
                    }   

                    else if (scoreFromGame < HighNum) 
                    {
                        tvLastScore.setText(Integer.toString(scoreFromGame));   
                    }
                }
            }   
        }

    }


    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onDestroy();
        mp.stop(); // Stops the mediaplayer when the game/emulator is exited.
        mp.release(); // Stops the mediaplayer when the game/emulator is exited.
    } 







    /*
    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState){ // When activity stops, system calls onSaveInstancState to save info.
        //Save the user's current game state
        savedInstanceState.putInt("GAME_SCORE", HighNum);
         super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState); //Calls superclass to view the hierachy state
    }

    @Override
    public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); // Calls the superclass first

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            HighNum = savedInstanceState.getInt("GAME_SCORE");
        } else {



        }

        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    }



    */




}
```

Comment: The method getSharedPreferences has to be after onCreate(). I think onResume() is ok. Shared prefs will only save key pairs until the app is destroyed. You can get your shared preferences in onResume, create an Editor with then. Then write and commit whenever the high score is created. Call them in OnResume() to populate the high score again. But again this will be lost if the app is destroyed. Maybe use SQLite?

Comment: OK thankyou! Is there anyway you could give me an example of how I would set and get the shared preferences, based on my code above?   If I create onPause to set the shared preferences.               SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences("myPrefsKey", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
Editor editor = prefs.edit();
editor.putInt("key", score);
editor.commit();                                                                                    What would I change to get take the score from my game? It's currently stored in the tvhighscore text view in the above code.

Comment: You put the high score in a textView, but the actually score is in scoreFromGame and set if greater than HighNum. When you check HighNum you should set the prefs as well. Put all the code you have above(in the comment) in a function and call it from the if(scoreFromGame>HigNum) passes true part and pass the scoreFromGame. Then use editor.setInt("hightScore", scoreFromGame

Answer (score 2):

You should look into the [Android Activity lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html) if you don't fully understand the lifecycle of an activity. The image demonstrates the states your activity can be in, and the functions you call to switch between these.

[image]

You should be able to save your preferences in the onPause, and load the preferences in the onResume function of your activity class. This means your preferences will be saved/loaded everytime the activity is closed/opened.

Comment: OK thankyou! Is there anyway you could give me an example of how I would set and get the shared preferences, based on my code above? If I create onPause to set the shared preferences. SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences("myPrefsKey", Context.MODE_PRIVATE); Editor editor = prefs.edit(); editor.putInt("key", score); editor.commit(); What would I change to get take the score from my game? It's currently stored in the tvhighscore text view in the above code.

Comment: You will get the preferences object in the same way, then it should be something like:

prefs.getInt(KeyString, DefaultValue)

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html